# Firefox extension for tab history navigation

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm using a tree-style tab bar with many tabs open, and often jump between them.

Is there a way or add-on that allows me to **switch to the tab I was on before**?

*Note that I do not mean to jump to the left or right neighbour tab (Strg-PageUp/Down), but to the tab that was focused last - like history back/forward, but with tabs.*

Comment: On before? was that tab closed, or is that tab or page still open?

Comment: Still open. I am on some tab, press say Alt-6 to go to tab 6, and after some time I want to go *back*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) has this option: Events -> Tab Features -> <kbd>Ctrl-Tab</kbd> navigates tabs in the most recently used order.

Also, [LastTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lasttab/) and [Most Recent Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/most-recent-tab/) do the job as well.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Vimperator users can jump to the last-used tab with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>.

I use Vimperator together with Tree Style Tabs and I use this feature often.